# Using get_success_url on a DeleteView when relevant data has been removed

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

In a Django application working with recipes I have subclassed `DeleteView` to create my `IngredientListItemDeleteView`, but I would like the result of `get_success_url` to depend on a property of the item that was just deleted.

I would like to do something like this:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    item = get_object_or_404(IngredientListItem, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])   # -> 404
    return this_item.recipe.get_absolute_url()
```

I understand that I get a 404 error because the item in question no longer exists but I have had no luck storing the relevant information about the item (namely, its containing recipe) before it gets deleted. For instance, if I put into the `get` method any code like

```
self.success_url = get_object_or_404(IngredientListItem, 
                                pk=self.kwargs['pk']).recipe.get_absolute_url()
```

then by the time `success_url` is looked at (after deletion), it has the value None.

How can I make my success URL depend on this property of the deleted item?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Django 1.6, the [`delete`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.6.x/django/views/generic/edit.py#L245) method has been changed so that the `get_success_url` method is called *before* the object is deleted.

```
def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Calls the delete() method on the fetched object and then
    redirects to the success URL.
    """
    self.object = self.get_object()
    success_url = self.get_success_url()
    self.object.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
```

I recommend you override your delete method as above, until you upgrade to Django 1.6. If you need to do this for multiple classes, you could create a mixin.

Note that you don't need to fetch the item from the database with `get_item_or_404` -- you can access it in your `get_success_url` method as `self.object`.

Comment: Thanks -- but just to clarify, I need to define self.object = self.get_object() before I can actually use self.object. Thanks for the tip though -- seems better than using get_item_or_404